# PHP date() adds an hour to return value

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display the length of time a user has been logged in. I have it working except for once thing. The hours part of the time starts at 1 and not 0.

Here is the PHP code:

```
//Set the local timezone to GMT
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//Fetch the timestamp for when user logged in
$loggedins = $conn->query ("SELECT Last_Activity FROM students WHERE Full_Name = '$name'");
$loggedinr = $loggedins->fetch_assoc();
$dateloggedin = strtotime($loggedinr['Last_Activity']);

//Separate the time from the above
$timelogin = date("h:i:s", $dateloggedin);
$timenow = date("h:i:s");

//Work out the time spent logged in
$sessionlength = strtotime($timenow)-strtotime($timelogin);

$sessionlength = date("H:i:s", $sessionlength);
```

** The Last_Activity column in the database contains: 2020-07-08 10:07:58

Here is the HTML:

```
<p style="line-height: 40px">Session length: <b><?= $sessionlength?></b></p>
```

This is what the page displays after being logged in for 13mins:

Session length: **01:13:44**

The following amendment shows the correct time (00:13:44)

```
$sessionlength = date("H:i:s", $sessionlength-3600);
```

Why does it add an hour? Any **constructive** help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a newbie to PHP but does it adjust for the daylight saving hour so from gmt to bst??

Comment: Thanks Siobhan, yes but I think it does that automatically anyway

Comment: i replicated your code and its working fine for me, $sessionlength = 02:22:06 for $dateloggedin = strtotime("2020-07-08 10:07:58") and current time 12:32 EDIT : nevermind i forgot its London time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot figure out why it's adding an hour, i think the assumption of Siobham makes the most sense, I tried setting the timezone to simply "Europe" and its printing the correct time, but if i add Paris it adds an hour.

Here is what seems to be a more reliable solution

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2020-07-08 10:07:58');//start time
$datetime2 = new DateTime($timenow);//end time
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```